# Is using Promise.await instead of async/await correct?

Tags: javascript, meteor, async-await

When performing some new operations in my project, I learned that db.aggregate should be executed asynchronously:

```
db.aggregate(
                        [
                            {
                                $match: { "records": { $exists: true, $ne: NaN } }
                            },
                            {
                                $group: { _id: "$recordkey", _avg: { $avg: "$records" } }
                            }
                        ]
                    ).toArray());
```

I could not change the calling code to async but I found that simply wrapping the function above into `Promise.await()`will work.
Is this a correct way that I can use? I do not really get how exactly it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Promise.await()` to make the `db.aggregate()` function call asynchronous.

`Promise.await()` is a function that allows you to wait for a promise to resolve before continuing with the execution of the function. When you call `Promise.await()` on a promise, the function will wait for the promise to resolve or reject before continuing with the execution of the code.

In your case, calling `db.aggregate()` returns a promise, and you want to wait for the promise to resolve before continuing with the execution of your code. By using `Promise.await()` on the `db.aggregate()` call, you are telling the function to wait for the promise to resolve before moving on to the next line of code.

That's how it works ^_^

Comment: Please note that it will no longer work the way expected once Fibers are fully dropped in upcoming Meteor 3.0